# Append N Unicode to string literal

Tags: sql

I have below problem.When we write a query as below the below output gives question mark.

Scenario 1

```
declare @input NVARCHAR(2000)='اتحاد'
SELECT @input
```

output

```
?????
```

---

Scenario 2

```
declare @input NVARCHAR(2000)=N'اتحاد'
SELECT @input
```

output

```
اتحاد
```

---

Let me know how to append N literal dynamically as below

```
declare @input NVARCHAR(2000)='اتحاد'
SET @input =N''+ @input
```

but the above yields:

```
?????
```

Comment: You cannot. `N'` is a signal to the *parser* that what follows should be interpreted as unicode. By the time you've stored that literal into a variable, it's **too late** to change how that literal was interpreted.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not change how the value was interpreted AFTER it's stored, so you MUST use Scenario 2 if you don't want to get question marks.

Comment: But i cannot use scenario2 as my value comes dynamically from the UI

Comment: seems a bit complicated, it's hard to help suggesting solutions as we don't know how your program is working, but have you tried sending the information through a table ? i can help keeping the letters in arabic and you can always empty that table after finishing your procedure (or empty it before you fill it)

Comment: arabic values come from .net code as parameter to the procedure without  'N' character if that is not there then it will return output ?

Comment: the idea is that instead of having a procedure with a parameter, you make a table (maybe just one column and obviously one row), at the .net code you empty the table then insert the value, then call the procedure, the procedure will just get the value from the table and proceed with it, this work around may help if you can't find a better solution, as the arabs say " للضرورة أحكام "...

Comment: tried but into that table only the value is coming as ???? so i have handled on .net side

Comment: the column in the table was `varchar` or `nvarchar` ?

Comment: [here is an example](https://imgur.com/a/MFppUM4) and it saves it as it is for `nvarchar` column, but as question marks for `varchar` column